# How to Add Custom Quote Discount on Product Line

Tags: magento2, quote, discount

I'm trying to add custom discount amount on quote to specific product line,
I saw event sales_quote_address_discount_item, when I use it like that :

```
    $item = $observer->getData('item');
    $item->setDiscountAmount(10);
    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(10);
    $item->save();
```

In database (quote_item) I can see that column 'discount_amount' and 'base_discount_amount' contains my amount, but nothing on quote table and on quote_address.

How can I apply from code a custom discount on one specific product in quote ?

Comment: What event are you hooking onto? I've had success using `sales_quote_item_set_product`

Comment: hi @dharth, have you got the correct answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

We are saving custom discount on line item level  i.e in quote_item table

Please follow the below steps:

1. Create sales.xml file in your custom module inside etc directory

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
       <section name="quote">
         <group name="totals">
           <item name="customdiscount" instance="[VendorName]\[Namespace]\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Discount" sort_order="500"/>
         </group>
      </section>
   </config>
   ```
2. create discount.php in [VendorName]/[Namespace]/Model/Quote/Address/Total

Note : This is not the complete code but it will help you to save the custom discount on item level.

```
    namespace [VendorName]\[Namespace]\Model\Quote\Address\Total;

    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

    class Discount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
       {

/** @var $_productRepository */
protected $_productRepository;

/**
 * Discount constructor.
 * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    ProductRepository $productRepository

) {
    $this->setCode('customdiscount');
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;

}

/**
 * Collect address discount amount
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
 * @return $this
 */
public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    $data = $quote->getItems();
    if (!count($data)) {
        return $this;
    }
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

        /** Custom Discount is saved in line item level (i.e in quote_item) */
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            if ($item['has_children']) {
                $product = $this->_productRepository->get($item['sku']);
            } else {
                $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($item['product_id']);
            }
                           $item->setDiscountAmount([setyourcustomdiscount]);
                            $item->setBaseDiscountAmount([setyourcustomdiscount]);
                            $item->setTaxAmount([setcustomTax]);
                            $item->setBaseTaxAmount([setcustomTax]);

      }

   }
```

Comment: I tried but problem is still the same, values are ok on item but not on total. On table quote the grand_total, subtotal_with_discount doesn't take discount

Comment: Maybe I need to add my values to the total like that : $total->addTotalAmount() ?

Comment: @dharth yes you have to set the values in $total.
Here is an example :
        $discountAmount = [customDiscountTotal];
        $total->setDiscountAmount([customDiscountTotal]);
        $total->setBaseDiscountAmount([customDiscountTotal]);
        $total->setTaxAmount([customTaxTotal]);
        $total->setBaseTaxAmount([customTaxTotal]);
        $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);

       Note : customDiscountTotal is sum of custom discount amount applied to each product in cart .

Comment: @RenuMishra can we use `$quote->collectTotals()` method to get total?

Comment: @umar yes, It is possible to get Grand Total  
Sub Total : $quote->collectTotals()->getSubtotal();
 Grand Total :$quote->collectTotals()->getGrandTotal();

Comment: @RenuMishra, After applying custom discount at item level? will it show in admin grid order view page?

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes it will show in admin order view as well because we are saving the data in item level and quote_item  to order_item will save the tax as well.

Comment: @RenuMishra, In my case its not showing but only discount applied

Comment: @RenuMishra, can u pls update the full code.. Along with the totals.

Comment: @RenuMishra, pls update full code, I used exactly same but custom discount not getting applied to any of the quote item

Comment: @RenuMishra, what is $this->getCode(), pls update full code for this

Comment: This code can be used to update any quote pricing data and also include any custom price component and can be used customize totals as well. But very important thing is `sort_order="***"` part and this decides when your code runs and if sort order is lower than magento's sort order then magento can override your custom value.